# Error with making filter for linelistrecord/fetch

Tags: fetch

I want to leverage the C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake to look for line list records where the patient has a chronic disease. I'm using `linelistrecord/fetch`. How do I construct the correct filter for this?

The POST request body that I tried was

```
{"spec" : {"filter" : "chronicDisease"}}
```

But I got the following error:

```
"ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying".
```

Comment: Please provide code and examples.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use `{"spec" : {"filter" : "exists(chronicDisease)"}}`.

As the error says, it needs to evaluate to a boolean. 
Other options that also work:

- `"length(chronicDisease) > 0"`
- `"chronicDisease != ''"`